# Laravel Caching Issue General / with Components

Tags: laravel, caching, components, laravel-livewire

I recently learned about caching in Laravel in a video series and wanted to apply it to my projects.

In this example project, I'm using a Livewire fullpage component (index) with 2 "modal" components each containing a "select" component which selects all records of a database table as a dropdown.

```
//Select Component Render Method
public function render()
{
    $this->options = $this->modelName::orderBy($this->attribute, 'ASC')->get();

    return view('components.input-field.select');
}
```

[Select_Component_Controller_Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiOre.png)

[Select_Frontend_Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUs5Q.png)

My problem here is that this component is called in both the create modal and the edit modal.
This causes a duplicate database query to be executed.

[Double_Query_Executed_DebugBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCsQq.png)

Unfortunately I am not quite clear how to apply the caching correctly now, in the example below you can see what I am trying to achieve. I would be very grateful for tips on the problem or even tutorial suggestions on the subject of caching, as I do not yet understand the application to this properly.

```
public function render()
{
    $this->options = cache()->remember("options", 20, function() {
        $this->modelName::orderBy($this->attribute, 'ASC')->get();
    });

    return view('components.input-field.select');
}
```

[try_to_accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBHKw.png)

With kind regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return the results in callback

```
  $this->options = cache()->remember("options", 20, function() {
           return $this->modelName::orderBy($this->attribute, 'ASC')->get();
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, im feeling so dumb right now.
I thought I had completely misunderstood something here. Works now.